# Calculating Average Days Missed by Employees

Tags: c++

Solved

*Thank you Paul, my issue ended up being really simple and I just made it unnecessarily convoluted which just furthered the issue. The issue ended up being the fact that I put an unnecessary cin in the if negative statement of the function which lead to it adding that negative somewhere along in calculation.*

*I will be leaving the code the same in the original post now just incase other people need assistance with an issue of this nature.*

*Alright, so I'm having a bit of a dilemma with this code. It is meant to calculate the average days missed by the employees at a company.*

*Comments removed, but the issue is that when negative numbers are encountered the total(daysM) is still subtracted from through means of days still ending up equal to a negative.*

*I tried to counteract this by using a daysforneg variable to account for any negative numbers until a positive integer is inputted, but it results in the same issue*

My question is how would I get a loop within the numMissed function as well as the do-while loop to work that disallows negative numbers without the issue persisting? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

/* prototypes */
int numEmp();
int numMissed(int);
double avgDays(int, int);
/////////////////////
/* Full functions */

int numEmp()
{
 int employees;
 cout<<"How many employees are in the company? ";
 cin>>employees; 
 while(employees<1)
 {
    cout<<"Invalid answer. Try again: ";
    cin>>employees;
 }
 return employees;
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int numMissed(int employees)
{
    int daysforneg;                 ///negative numbers
    int daysM=0,days;               ///Days is days missed per employee
    int x=0;
    do
    {
        cout<<"How many days were missed by these employees in the past year? ";
        cin>>days;
        if(days>=0)
        {
            daysM+=days;                //Calcs total days missed throughout
            x++;
        }
        else if(days<0)
        {
            cout<<"No negative numbers, sorry. Try again: ";    
            cin>>daysforneg;
            if(daysforneg>0)
            {
                x++;
                days=daysforneg;        
            }
            else
            {
                !(x++); 
            }                                   
        }                           
    }
    while(x<employees);                                         
    return daysM;
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
double avgDays(int daysM, int employees)
{
    double avg;
    avg=(daysM*1.0)/employees;
    return avg;
}

int main()
{
    int employees, daysM;
    double avg;
    employees=numEmp();
    daysM=numMissed(employees);
    avg=avgDays(daysM, employees);
    cout<<avg;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *how would I get a loop to work* -- There are other types of loops, such as `while` and `do-while`.  Use those instead of using `for` to automatically increment the counter when you don't want it incremented (assuming that is the issue).

Comment: When I referred to getting a loop to work I was referring to the if statements. I should have referred to them as if statements in hindsight because previously I had the negative number loop as a while loop so my brain was still registering them as just another loop.

Comment: Nonetheless though, I'm intrigued, how would I go about using a while loop as a count function? I'm unsure of how I would do so. Would it be like " while(x<employees) " with code following it?

Comment: Yes -- you increment `x` only when the employee data is "good".

Comment: Alright so using what you suggested, the same issue persists when encountering negative numbers except the issue of subtracting one from the average afterwards does not seem to present itself. The issue with the while loop is that it believes the number of employees to seemingly be 1 more than what it is when a negative number is inputted throughout the sequence of inputs.

Comment: Why is your original `for` loop doing any sort of calculations without first verifying that the input is good?  Why are you doing this: `daysM=daysM+days;`, before checking the validity of the input?  You've already corrupted the `daysM` calculation with the negative input.

Comment: Yeah I realized that when I was going through again, but even with changing it, when negative numbers are encountered it still subtracts from the total. I will update the code in the original post to fit these edits using the inputs of 5, 3, -1, 1, 2, 6, 9

Comment: *cout<<"No negative numbers, sorry. Try again: ";* --  So why aren't you just going back up to the top of the loop, i.e. `continue`?   I see `else if(days<0) { cout<<"No negative numbers, sorry. Try again: ";` then instead of just `continue`, a whole bunch of other things are done instead of simply "trying again".  The input is bad, no need to do anything else but start at the top of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the goal is to just "try again" if the input is negative, the loop can simply be done using a `while`:

```
int numMissed(int employees)
{

    int daysforneg;                 ///negative numbers
    int daysM=0,days;               ///Days is days missed per employee
    int x=0;
    while (x < employees )
    {
        cout<<"How many days were missed by these employees in the past year? ";
        cin>>days;
        if(days>=0)
        {
            daysM += days;  
            x++;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"No negative numbers, sorry. Try again: ";    
            continue;
        }  
    }
    return daysM;
}
```

The condition where the number of days that are input is negative, all that needs to be done is to go back up to the top of the loop without incrementing the counter `x`.